Possible to uniformly slide UV across non-rectangular quad?
This is a followup (root cause) to the question Sliding texture in U does not evenly cross wedge-shaped quad.
Given a quad, I want to slide a texture across it so that the interpolation is smooth. This works fine when the quad is rectangular (or subject to any affine transformation, including shearing it to a parallelogram). However, my quads are wedge-shaped. The implicit triangulation—which is required for rendering, even inside Blender—causes UVs to be interpolated across one diagonal or another. This causes very obvious non-uniform interpolation across the face of a wedge-shaped quad:

Is there any solution to this, other than massively subdividing the wedge on one or more axes (seen at right edge of image), which minimizes and hides the problem, but does not remove it?


It's possible within Blender, but it's not pretty.

Switch to the Cycles renderer and enable Open Shading Language.
Note that your viewports will now need to be in Rendered mode to see the result.
Write an OSL script (see below) to perform inverse bilinear interpolation on a quad of points - this takes the current position being rendered, uses four vertex points of the quad to find out what UV coordinate would map to that point using bilinear interpolation, and then uses that UV point to sample into a texture.
Where do you get the vertex coordinates? Well:

Add four custom attributes to the object.
Write a geometry nodes modifier that captures the positions at each index of the quad as outputs of the modifier. (Hint: this only works for a single mesh with four verts.)
Hook the output of that modifier up to the custom attributes.
Modify your custom material to read those attributes for the four corners to interpolate between.




float cross2d(point a, point b) {
    return a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
}

// https://iquilezles.org/articles/ibilinear/
point invBilinear(point a, point b, point c, point d, point x) {
    point e = b-a;
    point f = d-a;
    point g = a-b + c-d;
    point h = x-a;
    
    float k0 = cross2d(h, e);
    float k1 = cross2d(e, f) + cross2d(h, g);
    float k2 = cross2d(g, f);

    if (abs(k2) < 0.001) {
        // edges are parallel; lerp
        float my_u = (h.x*k1 + f.x*k0)/(e.x*k1 - g.x*k0);
        float my_v = -k0/k1;
        return point(my_u, my_v, 0.0);
    } else {
        float w = k1*k1 - 4.0*k0*k2;
        if (w < 0.0) return point(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
        w = sqrt(w);

        float ik2 = 0.5/k2;
        float my_v = (-k1 - w)*ik2;
        float my_u = (h.x - f.x*my_v) / (e.x + g.x*my_v);
        
        if (my_u<0.0 || my_u>1.0 || my_v<0.0 || my_v>1.0) {
           my_v = (-k1 + w)*ik2;
           my_u = (h.x - f.x*my_v)/(e.x + g.x*my_v);
        }
        return point(my_u, my_v, 0.0);
    }
}

shader BilinearMapping(
    point A = point(-1.5, 1.0, 0.0), 
    point B = point( 1.5, 1.0, 0.0), 
    point C = point( 0.5, -1.0, 0.0),
    point D = point(-0.5, -1.0, 0.0),
    string image_name = "/abs/path/to/texture/file.png",
    output closure color Emission = 0
) {
    point my_uv = invBilinear(A, B, C, D, P);
    color img = texture(image_name, my_uv.x, my_uv.y);
    
    // Since texture() bypasses Blender's Color Space adjustments
    // manually correct from sRGB to linear color space
    img.r = (img.r<=0.04045) ? img.r/12.92 : pow((img.r+0.055)/1.055, 2.4);
    img.g = (img.g<=0.04045) ? img.g/12.92 : pow((img.g+0.055)/1.055, 2.4);
    img.b = (img.b<=0.04045) ? img.b/12.92 : pow((img.b+0.055)/1.055, 2.4);

    Emission = emission() * img;
}

This is a single planar quad using bilinear interpolation:

…and here is the same quad with default UVs influenced by triangularization:

To meet the original goals, add an offsetU parameter to the shader, and animate it:


It is perhaps interesting to note that a bilinear mapping is not the same as a perspective-correct reprojection. Compare the difference between using Photoshop's four-point free distort and this bilinear mapping: distort-vs-bilinear.gif.
